# The java version in "mvn -version" is different from the version in "java -version" for mac

Tags: java, maven, version

[image: JAVA VERSION]

[image: JAVAVERSION]

As the screenshot shows, the java version is different, how can I change the java version in maven to 1.8?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Few things to debug

1. Please check for the `cat /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/bin/mvn` (maven uses this if present) - not sure if this has anything with `homebrew` installed maven. If there are any hardcoded versions, it might cause a difference in behavior.
2. `echo $JAVA_HOME` (maven uses this path and complains if not found)
3. did you set `JAVA_HOME` explicitly in any of the terminal sessions?

Also, how did you install java and maven? are they both installed using `homebrew`?

### Additional info

1. the following alias will help to switch between java versions easily

```
alias java11="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`"
alias java8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`"
```

2. this can be added to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`